# Adding multiple calendar IDs and attendee emails to events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, integration

I have a script to automate our calendar based off of a google sheet schedule we have. It does work in adding an event to a specific calendar, but I would like to add individual calendars to the script as well as automatically add a google group as the guests to the event so notifications go out like normal google calendar events.

```
   function scheduleShifts() {
/**
  Task 1) Open the Event Calendar.
**/
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);

/**
  Task 2) Pull each shift information into the code, in
  a form that the code can understand. 
**/
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A5:C100").getValues();

/**
    [
      [11/9/2019 0:00:00,11/10/2019 0:00:00,Werdah On-Call],
      [11/10/2019 0:00:00,11/11/2019 0:00:00,Lucas On-Call],
      [11/16/2019 0:00:00,11/17/2019 0:00:00,Aiden On-Call],
      [11/17/2019 0:00:00,11/18/2019 0:00:00,Werdah On-Call],
      [11/23/2019 0:00:00,11/24/2019 0:00:00,Mayra On-Call],
      [11/24/2019 0:00:00,11/25/2019 0:00:00,Kyle On-Call],
      [11/30/2019 0:00:00,12/1/2019 0:00:00,Cavan On-Call],
      [12/1/2019 0:00:00,12/2/2019 0:00:00,Adam On-Call],
      [12/7/2019 0:00:00,12/8/2019 0:00:00,Hillary On-Call],
      [12/8/2019 0:00:00,12/9/2019 0:00:00,Melissa Pino On-Call],
      [12/14/2019 0:00:00,12/15/2019 0:00:00,Kristi On-Call],
      [12/15/2019 0:00:00,12/16/2019 0:00:00,Kevin On-Call],
      [12/21/2019 0:00:00,12/22/2019 0:00:00,Alice On-Call],
      [12/22/2019 0:00:00,12/23/2019 0:00:00,Carro On-Call],
      [12/28/2019 0:00:00,12/29/2019 0:00:00,Sruthi On-Call],
      [12/29/2019 0:00:00,12/30/2019 0:00:00,Tara On-Call]
    ]  
**/

/**
  Task 3) Do the work!
**/
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

var shift = signups[x];

var startTime = shift[0];
var endTime = shift[1];
var oncall = shift[2];

eventCal.createEvent(oncall, startTime, endTime);
  }
}

/**
  Task 4) Make it easy to ue.
**/
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Schedule shifts now','scheduleShifts')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Can you give a very specific example of what you want to do? Something that we can tangibly solve with a small test data set? I'm not sure if you are asking to edit someone else' calendar without their permission?

Comment: What I am wanting to do is to update cells in certain columns of a google sheet and it push calendar invites to those individuals in order to notify folks of on-call days. Currently, we just list them in a sheet and call them out in a slack channel. I have noticed people miss those slack messages since we have so many channels to stay on top of during the day. The script does push the calendar event, but does not assign an email so someone gets a standard notification. also, want to call on more than one calendar ID.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is change your event creation code to use the [`createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app.html#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options) function.

With this you can add an object as the 4th parameter like this:

```
{
  "guests": "email1,email2,email3,groupsemail,etc",
  "sendInvites": true,
  "description": "Maybe you want to add more details? Up to you"
}
```

So, make sure you edit your `eventCal.createEvent(oncall, startTime, endTime);` to have the extra argument.

Also, you might want to create a list of emails to be auto-added and a key,value pair for tying names and emails together.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help here. I am new to writing scripts, basically just reverse engineer scripts I find in my research. So, I understand what you are saying, but struggle in putting it together within the script. Where am I adding your lines of code? Between task 3 and 4 of the script (line 45) and then adding the 4th object? Also, how can I set this to run a specific date only once? Each time I run the macro, it reruns everything all over again. Any help here would be appreciated.